# How to generate table with Angular ng-repeat using a JSON Map response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to generate a table as listed below using two APIs with Angular ng-repeat? How do I achieve this

```
+---------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
|   Continent   | Continent Shortcode |    City    | Population |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| Asia          | AS                  | Beijing    | 21.5       |
|               |                     | Manila     | 1.6        |
| Europe        | EU                  | London     | 8.6        |
|               |                     | Paris      | 2.2        |
| North America | NA                  | Washington | 7          |
| South America | SA                  | Brasilia   | 2.5        |
| Australia     | AU                  | Canberra   | 0.3        |
+---------------+---------------------+------------+------------+
```

REST endpoint for `getCityStatsByContinent(continentId)`-> 
**/api/statistics/cities/list?continent=100,200,300,400,500**

```
{
    "100" : [{
            "city" : "Beijing",
            "population" : 21.5m
        }, {
            "city" : "Manila",
            "population" : 1.6m
        }
    ],
    "200" : [{
            "city" : "London",
            "population" : 8.6m
        }, {
            "city" : "Paris",
            "population" : 2.2m
        }
    ],
    "300" : [{
            "city" : "Washington",
            "population" : 7m
        }
    ],
    "400" : [{
            "city" : "Brasilia",
            "population" : 2.5m
        }
    ],
    "500" : [{
            "city" : "Canberra",
            "population" : 0.3m
        }
    ],
}
```

REST endpoint for `getContinetDetails()`-> **/api/continents**

```
[   
    {
        "id" : 100,
        "code" : "AS",
        "name" : "Asia"
    }, {
        "id" : 200,
        "code" : "EU",
        "name" : "Europe"
    }, {
        "id" : 300,
        "code" : "NA",
        "name" : "North America"
    }, {
        "id" : 400
        "code" : "SA",
        "name" : "South America"
    }, {
        "id" : 500,
        "code" : "AU",
        "name" : "Australia"
    }
]
```

I could only think of starting with the below code (assuming first API response stored in citiesByContinentId). But I am stuck as what should be the right approach to resolve the continentId from the /api/continents

```
<tr ng-repeat ="(continentId, cityStats) in citiesByContinentId">
    <td>{{ continentId }}</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.ctiyPopulation = {
      "100": [{
        "city": "Beijing",
        "population": "21.5 m"
      }, {
        "city": "Manila",
        "population": "1.6 m"
      }],
      "200": [{
        "city": "London",
        "population": "8.6 m"
      }, {
        "city": "Paris",
        "population": "2.2 m"
      }],
      "300": [{
        "city": "Washington",
        "population": "7 m"
      }],
      "400": [{
        "city": "Brasilia",
        "population": "2.5 m"
      }],
      "500": [{
        "city": "Canberra",
        "population": "0.3 m"
      }]
    };

    $scope.continentDetails = [{
      "id": 100,
      "code": "AS",
      "name": "Asia"
    }, {
      "id": 200,
      "code": "EU",
      "name": "Europe"
    }, {
      "id": 300,
      "code": "NA",
      "name": "North America"
    }, {
      "id": 400,
      "code": "SA",
      "name": "South America"
    }, {
      "id": 500,
      "code": "AU",
      "name": "Australia"
    }];
  });
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Continent</th>
        <th>Continent Shortcode</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Population</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="continent in continentDetails">
      <tr ng-repeat="city in ctiyPopulation[continent.id]">
        <td><span ng-if="$index===0">{{continent.name}}</span></td>
        <td><span ng-if="$index===0">{{continent.code}}</span></td>
        <td>{{city.city}}</td>
        <td>{{city.population}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Assume $scope.continentDetails returns 100K records, will this not impact the performance doing ng-repeat on 100K records. Is this the only solution? or should this problem be solved differently?

Comment: In that case, you need to implement **pagination** and **single binding(`{{::city.city}}`)** for records.